# Form Data not sent via POST but works via GET in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post

This is pretty weird. I have tried everything. I see no notable issue here. Thought, may be either of you could lend me a helping hand in this issue. I am badly stuck here.

When I press the submit button in the form below, no data is sent. I am made sure that I did not miss the name attribute, but I totally do not understand the issue.

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

array
  empty

The most interesting part of this error is, if I set the method to GET, the values are passed.

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

GET Method Result:

```
array
  'song_file' => string '19 Jillian.m4a' (length=14)
  'song_name' => string 'Jillian' (length=7)
  'singer_name' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Heitor Pereira' (length=14)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
      5 => string '' (length=0)
  'lang' => 
    array
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
  'allow_downloading' => string 'yes' (length=3)
  'add_song' => string 'Add' (length=3)
```

The form code is as below. Here, I tried out with post method.

```
<form class="form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="label" for="song-file">Please select a track to upload*</label>
      <input id="song-file" name="song_file" class="field" type="file" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="label" for="song-name">Song Name :</label>
      <input id="song-name" name="song_name" class="field" type="text" size="42" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="label">Artists :</label>
      <div class="field-row">
        <input name="singer_name[]" class="field" type="text" size="25" />
        <input name="singer_name[]" class="field" type="text" size="25" />
      </div>
      <div class="field-row">
        <input name="singer_name[]" class="field" type="text" size="25" />
        <input name="singer_name[]" class="field" type="text" size="25" />
      </div>
      <div class="field-row">
        <input name="singer_name[]" class="field" type="text" size="25" />
        <input name="singer_name[]" class="field" type="text" size="25" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="label" for="allow-downloading"> Allow Downloading</label>
      <select name="allow_downloading" class="dropdown">
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="add_song" value="Add" class="btn" style="float:none;" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

As per the suggestion, here is a snippet of my PHP Code that this form uses:

P.S. I am using Code Igniter at the backend. All other forms are working well, expect for this one.

```
class Song extends CI_Controller {

    public function add($album_id){

        if($_POST){
            var_dump($_POST);
        }

        $this->load->view('album/form.php');
    }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: please show us a bit more of your php code.

Comment: And problem is with this method only. all other classes/pages are working perfectly fine.

public function add($album_id){

var_dump($_POST);

if($_POST){
// do something
}

$this->load->view('album/form.php');

}


here the form is being loaded... no issues on that

data is being passed thru GET method but not via POST.

Comment: please add this to your original post and probably the entire php code (i.e. where this function is invoked).

Comment: where is your form action ?

Comment: action="" will return the navigation to the same page.

so currently, I am invoking the URL: 

http://localhost/music/admin/song/add/1

so that will be my action URL whenever the form is submitted.

Comment: i tried ur code and every things sent by post method

Comment: yep. exactly... that's what I am saying... this is a big system and the same technique works everywhere not just here since day before yesterday. Lets see if I can find out something.

Comment: did u find anythig bro ?? :P

Comment: well, this been one of the weirdest issue, that I've ever encountered. I figured out the problem after two days. This problem particularly occurred when I tried to upload songs from just one particular folder ( now God knows why just that folder, because I had renamed or shortened the names, etc. everything)

Answer (score 0):

1. May be you have some JS submit handler, which, for example, prevent default submit action, collect all form data and send it through ajax with GET method?
2. May be CodeIgniter do some magic with POST data. To know it for sure dump $_POST array before CodeIgniter core initialization.